# How to dynamically detect grails asset updates in production?

Tags: grails

So we have resources in the grails-app/assets folder, i.e: javascript files, stylesheets and other documents.

Some of these documents are user docs which would have to have the option of being updated in production mode. When you usually add something to this assets folder, the grails app doesn't detect this change until after redeploying the app which would cause the folder to be reprocessed.

Is there any way to detect these changes in **production** systems or an alternate location other than the assets folder where grails would pick up this new/updated file without re-deployment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under production the most recommendable approach is to have an Apache Httpd or an NGinx server as a front end where you put the static assets. In both cases you will need configure reverse proxy on NGinx or mod_jk (depending of your Java container.).

Inclusive you may think on store large assets in a repository like S3 (if you will run on Internet).